# Loading properties file in GWT on Tomcat

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, properties

I know there are lots of similar questions out there, but none of which that helped.
We have a GWT application running on a tomcat server, which is loading a properties file for database connections.

The code to load the properties file looks like following:

```
private static final String DB_CONF = "com/x/monitorui/server/configuration.properties";
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(DatabaseConnection.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(DB_CONF));
```

This works fine whilst developing locally on the Jetty, but not when deployed on the Tomcat. It can't seem to find the resource.
The file itself is located in `war/WEB-INF/classes/com/x/monitorui/server`, the class trying to load it is located in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

Wo do nearly the same here with "Packager.class" as a class in the same directory; The idea here is to find the path via the class path, which works on tomcat:

```
final ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault( );
final Class<?> baseClass = Packager.class;
pool.insertClassPath( new ClassClassPath( baseClass ) );

final URL url = pool.find( baseClass.getName( ) );

String pathToBaseClass = url.toURI( ).getPath( );
String baseDir = pathToBaseClass.substring( 0, pathToBaseClass.indexOf( "com" ) - 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you properties file is in the same directory as the class you use to call "getResourceAsStream(..)", then you just need the name of the file, without the absolute path to it.
For example, supposing you have:

```
// notice that your build should copy this from the source directory to your /WEB-INF/classes/.... directory automatically so you can do a clean build
com/x/monitorui/server/configuration.properties
```

and a class located at the same directory, ie. in package:

```
com.x.monitorui.server.DatabaseConnection
```

then you can simply call

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(DatabaseConnection.class.getResourceAsStream("configuration.properties"));
```

Comment: By the way, I use tomcat as well and this works fine, I would think this should work with any server.