# GWT Maven build with maven profiles

Tags: gwt, maven

I'm attempting to use capabilities provided by maven profiles to build customized builds for different server environments.  What I'm attempting to do is combine maven resource filtering

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

with it's profile mechanism

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>mock</id>
        <properties>
            <application-url>http://mock-server-url</application-url>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

to convert this value in a file named `server.cfg`

```
${application-url}
```

to something I can use here:

```
public interface ServerResource extends ClientBundle {
    public static final ServerResource INSTANCE =  GWT.create(ServerResource.class);

    @Source("server.cfg")
    public TextResource server();

}
```

I can see that the value's been replaced in WEB-INF/classes but it doesn't appear that GWT used the file with the replacement to create the application javascript.  How can I do this?

Comment: It looks to me as you are hardcompiling in specific server properties in your GWT application. Is there are reason you don't get those values from the server via for example an Async callback when your application starts? This way you don't need to compile multiple versions in the first place.

Comment: I'm a little new to this, so if I download my GWT app from my_server/instance1, how would callback know to go to my_server/instance1_services.  This is ultimately what I want to do - and then have another application instance at my_server/instance2 and myserver/instance2_services.  I tried to use ExternalSourceResource, but had no success with that.  I've also looked into GIN, and couldn't figure that out either.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you exactly mean with `services`? Is it a separate deployed application? Are they actual webservice or GWT RPC servlets? How do you communicate with those services?

Comment: Yes, it is a separate deployed RESTful web service application.  I communicate with them over HTTP (and HTTPS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved what I was trying to accomplish without the use of maven profiles or the GWT ClientBundle (which I never did get to work in the way I had intended when I wrote the question).

Here were the main issues I hoped to solve using maven profiles and the workaround I employed to solve the issue at hand:

1. **Use Mock MVP Models in Hosted Mode**

   ```
   // inside the initialization for my model locator
   boolean hostedMode = GWT.getPermutationStrongName().equals("HostedMode");

   if (hostedMode) {
      // instantiate mock models
   } else {
      // instantiate real models to call REST web services
   }
   ```
2. **Provide real models with correct RESTful server URL**

   I was able to accomplish this because my GWT app and the RESTful web service url follow a set naming convention.  I basically strip the trailing '/' from the URL and append '_services"

   ```
   String createServicesBaseUrl() {
       StringBuffer baseUrl = new StringBuffer(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL());
       int length = baseUrl.length();
       baseUrl.replace(length-1, length, "_services");
       return baseUrl.toString();
   }
   ```
3. **Enable testing of as much of the MVP Presenter (Activities & Places) as I could**

   I was already injecting the model locator into my `Activity` classes, so replacing that with a mock model locator for use by JUnit was straightforward.  I did the same for my views and abstracted away some of the other code which didn't seem to work outside of the browser (like the GWT `PlaceController`).

All in all my build is much the same, but I learned how to gain a lot of flexibility in testing, configuring the server instance my GWT application connects with, and which model my application uses (dependent on hosted vs server mode).

Comment: Now I see what you were trying to do... interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Using GWT compiler permutations to apply this kind of configuration is in my opinion a very bad idea. One of the most common complaints about GWT is the time it takes to compile, and by doing this you're just adding to the problem.

Configuration should usually be read from configuration files (surprise!), like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410763/loading-properties-file-in-gwt-on-tomcat/9411606#9411606).

Anyway, what you're trying to do seems to me impossible. You cannot tell the client-side code to which server it should connect. This would violate the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)! The app can only communicate with the server it came from.

To have different apps running in different URLs, you would need to deploy several GWT apps with different names (even if they are basically the same). Then, you would just have to type the correct URL for each app (version) in the browser, and it will "look" at the right app. So you could have URLs like this:

```
http://myserver.com/app1
http://myserver.com/app2
```

In order to make a request to a different app running in the same server as the GWT application, you can do something like this:

```
String serviceUrl = "/app2/someService"; // or some other String sourced from a config file, using a GWT ClientResource for example
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,
            serviceUrl);
    try {
        // send request from app1 to app2
        rb.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                    Response response) {
                log.info("Response: " + response.getStatusText());
                // if response is 200 it's ok, you can read the outputStream to see what's in there
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                log.warning("Request Error", exception);
                // do something more
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        log.warning("Request Exception", e);
        // getting here means trouble with the connection or service!
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't violate the same origin policy since it's going to the same server, just a different instance on the server - and I need to specify which instance it is.  Flex has similar SOP restrictions, and we're attempting to replace our Flex UI with GWT.  What you've suggested later in your post about different app versions is what I'm attempting to do - it's just that app1 uses app1_web_services and app2 uses app2_web_services.  I need to specify that mapping someplace.  In Flex I did it in the war packaging.  I'll look at your configuration example.  Thanks!

Comment: The configuration file example you reference looks like it sets the configuration for server-side components.  Is that true? What I want to do is set this type of configuration on client side components (visible to the js generated by the gwt compiler).

Comment: BTW - I'd happily trade slow compile time performance for fast(er) run time performance.

Comment: From what you wrote, it appeared to me you wanted to set the URL of the server you want to connect to. This would be impossible.You're mixing things up... when you use GWT.create(...), you're using deferred-binding (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html). This does not have anything to do with maven profiles. I use Maven profile to build a "dev" or "prod" environment ("dev" basically only compiles to one browser, so it's must quicker).

Comment: Please be more explicit about what you are trying to achieve, I think I might be able to help as I have played with deferred binding, Maven profiles and even GWT generators (which can do amazing things for you). I'm sure one of these solutions will do what you want (except connect to different servers).

Comment: I want app1 to use app1_web_services and app2 to use app2_web_services, they are all on the same server.  Somewhere I need to set app1_web_services in the client js so the client knows where the services are.  What I'd also like to do is use a mock model (no services) when the application is running from an embedded server (the default) so I can quickly prototype UI changes with data without needing to connect to any services.  In a pure java web app, I'd set these values in resource files and have maven set the values through its profile mechanism.  I'm trying to do the same here.

Comment: Maybe I could just use GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() and GWT.getPermutationStrongName() to do everything I need.

Comment: Actually - yes GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() and GWT.getPermutationStrongName() does what I need.

Comment: Great... simple solution is always better!

Comment: Let's try to write an answer that is useful for others.... I will edit my answer, then you can edit it further with any modifications you think are suitable, or you can just write another answer if you think I got it wrong.

Comment: I created an answer yesterday after I posted the comment, but SO wouldn't let me post it for some reason.  Trying again now.... BTW - I really appreciate all your help and insights.  This conversation was very useful to me.