# GWT Servlet communication

Tags: gwt, servlets

How do I create a servlet object on the server-side of GWT? I have two different classes on the back end, `ConfigServiceImpl` and `DatabaseServiceImpl` and I'd like to use `ConfigServiceImpl` servlet object in `DatabaseServiceImpl`. Basically `ConfigServiceImpl` loads a properties file via `getServletContext().getRealPath()` but I cannot use this without using a servlet object, but `GWT.create()` is only available client side. So how can this be done?

Comment: I am not sure, what you are asking for. Are both classes servlets? If yes, you may create a method witch converts a 'path' to 'realPath' by using the ServletContext as parameter.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach yes they are both servlets (well they both extend `RemoteServiceServlet`) but I get a null exception every time i call `getServletContext()`

Comment: I guess it is not a good idea to use an instance of the Impl class as an object. If you want to share objects between classes on the server, you could create a new object (not an instance of the impl) in your ConfigServiceImpl and a static getter for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load **.properties** files into GWT you need to use [Constants](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nConstants.html). You most definitely can't use a servlet class on the client code as there is no Javascript equivalent for that. If you have any questions on what parts on the Java API you would be able to use on client code for GWT, check the [compatibility list](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html).

Comment: Constants is not available server side

Comment: I guess I missunderstood your question then, I thought the problem was on the client side. Have you checked this one?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410763/loading-properties-file-in-gwt-on-tomcat